# What is the relationship between harmonic motion and the harmonics of a wave?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, harmonic-oscillator, harmonics

I learned about harmonic motion and harmonic oscillators a long time ago in physics, but I can't remember what the relationship between that and and the definition of harmonic in a wave.

A [harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic) is defined as a component frequency of an oscillation or wave.

But [harmonic motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) is periodic motion where the restoring force is proportional to the applied force, but the direction is opposite.

It feels like the two definitions are not related to me, almost as if we're using the word "harmonic" to mean two different things.

Answer (score 1):

ok, you know that plucking a guitar string makes it vibrate.  It vibrates up and down, up and down,  again and again in the same pattern until friction stops it.
a guitar string can emit different harmonics, but these are just higher or lower notes moving in the same regular pattern

Harmonic motion is a term used to describe the same idea, of a process repeating itself in a regular way

With harmonic motion, there must be a force available to make the object (whatever it is )  go back to it's original position, that's the minus restoring force.

So the term harmonic motion is a general term that applies to all "things" that follow a regular in/out, up/down etc. pattern.